# Is there a way to read in an http server (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, http, server

I have created a Server with Node.Js here is the Code

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/html');
    res.write(<input type="number" id="a">);
    res.write("<style> #a {text-align:center} </style>");
    /*Reading function */
    res.end();
});
server.listen(8000);
```

Is there a way to get the innerHTML of the input(From the Client)?

Maybe u can help me :)

(For further explaination: The client should open the website, write something in the number field, then i want the innerHTML of the number field send to the server)

Comment: The way you have written it, it's `""` ie the empty string. What do you intend to do with the innerhtml? Are you sure, you need this on the server and not on the client?

Comment: Yeah i want to get the data from the client

Comment: Then you have to read the value from the input in the client and post it back to the server ... There are myriads of tutorials out there how to do this ...

Comment: Could u send a link?